# Change order of polygons within a feature layer? (arcgis js 4.xx)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I have tried using the below in my initial query, and query right before drawing my polygons with class breaks.

```
    query.orderByFields = ["Shape__Area DESC"];
```

However this did not seem to do anything. I have also tried using **grid_value** field as well.

Here is my relevant code in which I am querying and then doing the drawing... main problem is occasionally large polygons block out smaller ones.. I can mostly see them, but visibility is not the issue.. I need to be able to click them as well.. if the smaller polygons would draw on top most layer, or even higher grid values on top should solve it. I found **orderByFields** in the docs but doesn't seem to do anything at all...

```
query.outFields = ["*"];
  //query.orderByFields = ["Shape__Area DESC"];
  query.returnDistinctValues = false;
  query.returnGeometry = true;
  QT.execute(query).then(function (evt) {
    evt.features.forEach(function (feature) {
      var att = feature.attributes
      var test = geometryEngine.convexHull(feature.geometry)
      var genpoly = null
      if (att.grid_value <= 4.0) {
        var rad = att.Shape__Length / 75
        genpoly = new Circle({
          center: test.centroid,
          radius: rad,
          radiusUnit: "meters"
        })
      } else {
        genpoly = test
      }
      var polygonGraphic = new Graphic({
        geometry: genpoly,
        attributes: att,
        type: "polygon"
      });
      gras.push(polygonGraphic);
    });
    var renderer = {
      type: "class-breaks",
      field: "grid_value",
      classificationMethod: "esriClassifyManual",
      classBreakInfos: [{
          minValue: 0,
          maxValue: 1.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "I (Not Felt)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 2.0,
          maxValue: 3.0,
          symbol: {
            color: [191, 204, 255, .3],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "II (Weak)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 3.1,
          maxValue: 3.9,
          symbol: {
            color: [153, 153, 255, .4],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "III (Weak)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 4.0,
          maxValue: 4.5,
          symbol: {
            color: [136, 255, 255, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "IV (Light)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 4.5,
          maxValue: 4.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [125, 248, 148, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "V (Light)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 6.0,
          maxValue: 6.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [255, 255, 0, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "VI (Strong)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 7.0,
          maxValue: 7.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [255, 221, 0, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "VII (Very Strong)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 8.0,
          maxValue: 8.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [255, 145, 0, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "VIII (Severe) "
        },
        {
          minValue: 9.0,
          maxValue: 9.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [255, 0, 0, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "IX (Violent)"
        },
        {
          minValue: 10.0,
          maxValue: 10.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [221, 0, 0, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "X"
        },
        {
          minValue: 11.0,
          maxValue: 11.9999,
          symbol: {
            color: [136, 0, 0, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "XI"
        },
        {
          minValue: 12.0,
          maxValue: 12.0,
          symbol: {
            color: [68, 0, 0, 1],
            outline: {
              color: [0, 0, 0, 0],
              width: 0.4,
              type: "simple-line",
              style: "solid"
            },
            type: "simple-fill",
            style: "solid"
          },
          label: "XII"
        }
      ]
    }
         var popupTrails = {
             outFields: ["*"],
             "title": "Shake ID: {id}",
            "content": function (feature){
              let name_plc;
              let dlv = document.createElement("div");
              dlv.className = "popd";
              dlv.innerHTML = `<b><span class='name_plc'></span></b><br>ID: <span class="ida">${feature.graphic.attributes.id}</span><br> URL: <a href="${feature.graphic.attributes.url}" target="_blank">View</a> <br> Updated: ${feature.graphic.attributes.updated} <br>Grid_value: ${feature.graphic.attributes.grid_value}<br> Event Time: ${feature.graphic.attributes.eventTime} <style>.esri-popup__navigation { display: none;}</style>`;
              
              getName();
              
              function getName() {
               let cId = $('span.ida').text();
               if (cId) { 
                  //console.log(cId);
                  let q3 = new Query();
                  q3.where = "id = '"+ cId +"'";
                  q3.outFields = ["*"];
                   QTt.execute(q3).then(function (results) {
                      results.features.map(function (feat) {
                        let pID = feat.attributes["id"];
                        if (cId === pID) {
                           name_plc = feat.attributes["place"];
                             console.log(name_plc);
                             let tx = $('.name_plc').text();
                             if (tx == 0){
                               $(".name_plc").append(name_plc);
                             }
                        }
                      });
                  });
              } else {
                setTimeout(getName, 230);
              }
             }
              return dlv; 
      },
    };
    fl = new FeatureLayer({
      source: gras,
      objectIdField: "ObjectID",
      geometryType: "polygon",
      fields: [{
        name: "ObjectID",
        alias: "ObjectID",
        type: "oid"
      }, {
        name: "id",
        alias: "id",
        type: "string"
      }, {
        name: "updated",
        alias: "Last Update",
        type: "string"
      }, {
        name: "eventTime",
        alias: "eventTime",
        type: "string"
      }, {
        name: "url",
        alias: "url",
        type: "string"
      }, {
        name: "grid_value",
        alias: "grid_value",
        type: "double"
      }],
      renderer: renderer,
      popupEnabled: true,
      //outFields: ['*'],
      popupTemplate: popupTrails,
      visibleElements: [{
          featureNavigation: false, 
      }],
    });
    map.add(fl);
```

Here is my full [CodePen](https://codepen.io/camerondevcam/pen/pogPZvX?editors=1100) as well.. Any way to do this client-side JavaScript? Simply change index to smallest polygons on top?! 1/3 times some of my polygons render in the correct order... But I need to ensure they all always do, so they are visible and I can click them.

*You can see in the screenshot a 3.8 grid value polygon overlapping making the inner 6.5 and 7.8 grid_value polygons in accessible to click.*

[image]

Comment: Currently it is NOT possible to change the order within one layer.

Comment: I suspected this; luckily I noticed I can access clicking the outline (after creating one) and then zooming in, seems to respond to the outline click even if it's behind another geometry. Others in the geoNets forums insisted 'Shape__Area DESC' works; but I never found it working consistently on all the shapes.

Answer (score 1):

Update: It was not possible in 2020, but as of version 4.21 it is.
And, it seems, you specify

```
orderByFields = ["Shape__Area DESC"]
```

on the featurelayer, not on the query:

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/4.21/#control-the-drawing-order-of-features